# using retrofit to make url?locations=lat,lon query

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to make a get query that has to look like this: url?locations=lat,lon

I tried this code :

```
@Query("locations") lat: List<Double>
```

but this ends up with url?locations=lat&lon

any idea how can I do to attain this url?

Comment: I think you can concatenate latitude to longitude with comma and use this string as the locations parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will only achieve what you want using the solution [BakhtiyorBegmatov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3969880/bakhtiyor-begmatov) mentioned:

```
@GET("locations")
suspend fun getLocations(
   @Query("locations") latLongString: String
) : List<Location>
```